# How to set a flex item to inherit the height of its flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

To be more specific, I have a flexbox:

```css
.main{
    display: flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
 
    -ms-flex: 3;
    -webkit-box-flex: 3;
    -moz-box-flex: 3;
    -ms-box-flex: 3;
    box-flex: 3;
    
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 100%
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.landing-img{
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    
    align-self: flex-end;
    height: inherit;
    
}
img{
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="landing-img">
    <img src="images/someimg.png" style="min-width:100%;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

in which the image extends out of its div element. I am trying to set the height of the image container to match height of its parent(main). I have tried to use the inherit, doesn't work. I tried height 100% doesn't work. [webpage i am working on to get a visual reference](http://www.diventify.com)

Comment: Start by correcting your html. You have `<hmtl>` as an opening tag in your code.